# Defining function that takes funciton as argument results in "Wrong type argument: commandp, (bm-my bm-next)"

Tags: spacemacs, interactive, funcall

When using the below and invoking the function via `<leader>Bn` I get an error of `command-execute: Wrong type argument: commandp, (bm-my bm-next)`

```
(defun bm-my (a)
  (interactive)
  (a)
  (bm-show-all)
  )

(spacemacs/set-leader-keys "Bn" '(bm-my bm-next))
```

What is the cause of the error? Essentially I'm trying to define a function that takes a function to be run, and then runs `bm-show-all` after it.

This mentions the function must be interactive (which mine is?)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250846/wrong-type-argument-commandp-error-when-binding-a-lambda-to-a-key

---

I've tried:

```
(defun bm-my (a)
  (interactive)
  (a)
  (bm-show-all)
  )

(spacemacs/set-leader-keys "Bn" (bm-my 'bm-next))
```

But that errors in the below when evaluating (with `eval-buffer`):

```
helm-M-x: Symbol’s function definition is void: a
```

Comment: 2 issues. First, your command requires an argument, but you don't pass it one when you invoke it via the keybinding.  Second, you need to use funcall to call the function in the body of the command, since you presumably mean to pass it a function symbol as the argument.

Comment: @Dan: Please consider posting that as an answer. (As you know, comments can be deleted at any time.)

Comment: Surely the argument is `a`, which I pass as `bm-next` to `bm-my`? I'll take a look at funcall now.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is elisp does not do "partial" functions - while I assume it does?

Comment: Ah, a third issue. You can only bind a key to an interactive function symbol, not a list of a function and argument.